# Background notification is not working in expo react native

Tags: expo-notifications

i am developing a react native expo app in which i need a scheduler which help me to notify me , for some specific time but in android this background notification is not working can anyone help me i need urgent.another thing in some mobile it is working but not in majority

```
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync()
      .then((token) => {
        console.log("token: ", token);
        if (customUser && token && customUser.expoPushToken !== token) {
          updateExpoPushToken(customUser.userId, token)
            .then((action) => {
              if (action) {
                dispatch(action);
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error registering for push notifications: ", error);
      });

    Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
      handleNotification: async () => ({
        shouldShowAlert: true,
        shouldPlaySound: true,
        shouldSetBadge: true,
      }),
    });

    notificationListener.current =
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
        setNotification(notification);
        console.log(
          "notification received: " + notification.request.content.body
        );
      });

    return () => {
      if (notificationListener.current) {
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(
          notificationListener.current
        );
      }
      if (responseListener.current) {
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
      }
    };
  }, [Notifications]);
  function redirect(notification: Notifications.Notification) {
    const url = notification.request.content.data?.url;
    if (url) {
      router.push(url);
    }
  }`
```

i tried expo push notification document and did same like them but didn't get successful result as it is working in some mobile mean i can receive background notification but not some mobile what to do